# Dont store empty field in database

Tags: html, database, forms

I have an issue with an optional field in an html form. The system is to send out newsletters, and a part of the form is that you choose the groups you want to send the newsletter to through the selection of checkboxes. There is a field for additional email addresses, in case the user wants to send the email to recipients not in the groups.

This field is what gives me the trouble. If there is no value entered in the field, it saves an empty register to the database, which leads to the sending process failing, since it tries to get an email address to send to.

So far the solutions I have seen are to assign a NULL value to the field if empty, or to assign another default value. but this will cause problems for some of the statistics that will be displayed to the user later on.

Is there any way to only store the value of this field if it is not empty? And to ignore it completely if it is?

(I'm using php, mysql, html for this)

Thank you!

SOLVED: I could make it work by separating the storing of the emails in the additional field from the rest of the emails. Then I just put an if(!empty($_POST['additional])) around it, and it works fine now.

Comment: Specify Not Null for that field

Comment: Please post your sql query.

Comment: Thanks guys, it works now, added the solution to the original post